# 127.0.0.1/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/output.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not supported stylesheet MIME

Tags: tailwind-css

I am creating a simple tailwind css dashboard and i am encountering issues with initial set up. I followed the doc instructions in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation. However, when i run the server i am getting "Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/output.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled,"[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnjwD.png)

below are my file structures in the project.
[files in my project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz38W.jpg)

Comment: This is a strong indication that the server sends a html error message instead of css. You should check your server code to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the server is not resolving the css file properly.

What you can do to resolve:

1. Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/output.css - Does it load up the CSS file? If it doesn't, then that path isn't exactly valid. You can try to bring out the css file to 'src' directly and link to it from there.
2. Another way to attempt a resolution is to link the css file like this
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/output.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Thanks. I realised i followed the wrong instructions when downloading tailwindcss. I created the project using vite. Hence i needed to install tailwindcss with vite. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

As i created the project using vite, I should have installed tailwind css using vite. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite.